# Qt popup search dialog

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I'm new to Qt and I'm trying to build a simple text editor. I want to have a search function and at the moment it is just a static toolbar on top of my text editor main window. What I would like, is kind of a popup-toolbar, like in chrome or Firefox that as soon as I choose "Find" from the menu or press Ctrl+F, the toolbar appears and as soon as I press close, it disappears.

I am also having some focus issues atm, if I press Ctrl+F, I don't get a blinking cursor at my `QLineEdit` and I am not sure why.

Any tips are welcome! Thanks in advance!

My `mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include"searchdialog.h"
#include <QToolBar>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


public slots:
    void open_search_window();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString m_filename;
    SearchDialog *m_dialog;
    QToolBar *m_toolbar;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Then, `mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "searchdialog.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_dialog = new SearchDialog();
    m_dialog->show();

    m_toolbar = new QToolBar(this);
    m_toolbar->addWidget(m_dialog);

    this->addToolBar(m_toolbar);

    connect(ui->actionquit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->actionFind, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open_search_window()));

    new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_F), this, SLOT(open_search_window()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete m_dialog;
}



void MainWindow::open_search_window()
{
    m_dialog->show();

}
```

And my own defined `Searchdialog` class:

```
#ifndef SEARCHDIALOG_H
#define SEARCHDIALOG_H
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QShortcut>

class SearchDialog : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SearchDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
    QLabel* m_label;

public slots:
    void find_next();

signals:
    void new_search(QString search_string);

private:
    QLineEdit* m_searchInput; 
    QPushButton* m_cancel;
    QPushButton* m_findNext;
};

#endif // SEARCHDIALOG_H
```

And `searchdialog.cpp`

```
#include "searchdialog.h"

SearchDialog::SearchDialog(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)

{
    this->setWindowTitle("Find stuff...");

    m_label = new QLabel(tr("Find what:"));
    m_searchInput = new QLineEdit;
    m_findNext = new QPushButton(tr("&Find"));
    m_cancel = new QPushButton(tr("&Close"));

    connect(m_cancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(m_findNext,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(find_next()));
    new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Enter), this, SLOT(find_next()));

    QHBoxLayout* findLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    findLayout->addWidget(m_label);
    findLayout->addWidget(m_searchInput);

    QHBoxLayout* buttonsLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    buttonsLayout->addWidget(m_findNext);
    buttonsLayout->addWidget(m_cancel);

    QVBoxLayout* windowLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    windowLayout->addLayout(findLayout);
    windowLayout->addLayout(buttonsLayout);

    this->setLayout(windowLayout);
}

void SearchDialog::find_next()
{
    if (!m_searchInput->text().isEmpty()) {
        QString searchString = m_searchInput->text();
        emit new_search(searchString);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use QLineEdit::setFocus to solve the focus issue. Is hiding/showing the toolbar instead of the lineedit not what you want?

Comment: well the lineedit is a part of my toolbar, and yes I want to know how to hide/show the toolbar. Right now it is always there.

Comment: Can't you use QToolBar::setVisible?

Comment: So trivial, yes, setVisible did the trick, thanks!

But there is an issue with setting the focus. If I set it in ´searchdialog.cpp´, it doesn't work. I set it right after ´this->setLayout(windowLayout);´ 
If I do it in mainwindow,cpp, it works, but I have to change my lineedit to a public variable then. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can add an extra function to `SearchDialog`, which set the focus for you.

Comment: Or you can convert `SearchDialog` to a `QToolBar` and add a function `popup` which call `QToolBar::setVisible` and `QLineEdit::setFocus` together.

Comment: I just overloaded `show` with an additional `setfocus`. Thank you for your tips @m7913d!

Comment: Can you formulate an answer yourself and mark is as correct? Other people with the same question may benefit from it.